# NodeJS Sharp Node Package Memory Consumption Issue

Tags: node.js, image-processing, memory-leaks, sharp

I am working on a NodeJS project that is using `sharp node package` for resizing JPEG/JPG images.

The problem is Node process keeps adding the processed file in memory and never releases it.

As a result, amount of memory consumed increases with every request & it never gets released.

After debugging the application, I realised that [sharp toBuffer API](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-output/#tobuffer) is causing the issue.

I tried using alternative solution by creating a `custom writable stream` and piping it with `sharp Duplex stream` but it ends up with the same problem.

I don't understand if I'm missing anything here or it's a bug.

Sharing the code below (I have removed unwanted code to make it compact) -

```
const { Writable } = require("stream");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const sharp = require("sharp");

async function resizeJpeg(input_buffer) {
    // initialise file, the response object
    const file = { normalisedImage: null, originalImage: null };
    // initialise sharp instance using original image buffer
    let image = sharp(input_buffer);
    // set the original image metadata
    file.originalImage = await image.metadata();
    file.originalImage.quality = 85;

    // generate buffer using sharp resize API with default quality & dimensions.
    // ############### THIS IS WHERE MEMORY CONSUMPTION OCCURS ###############

    // APPROACH 1 (SHARP toBuffer API)
    const buffer = await image.resize(2000, 798).jpeg({ quality: 85 }).toBuffer();
    // APPROACH 1 ENDS 

    // APPROACH 2 (CUSTOM WRITABLE STREAM)
    // const buffer = await sharpToBuffer(image.resize(2000, 798).jpeg({ quality: 85 }));
    // APPROACH 2 ENDS

    // set resized image metadata
    file.normalisedImage = await sharp(buffer).metadata();
    file.normalisedImage.quality = 85;
    return file;
}

// converts sharp readable stream to buffer using custom writable buffer
async function sharpToBuffer(readable) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const writable = new WriteStream().on("finish", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(writable.bufferChunks)));
        readable.pipe(writable);
    });
}

// simple writable stream
class WriteStream extends Writable {
    constructor() { super(); this.bufferChunks = [] }
    _write(chunk, encoding, next) { this.bufferChunks.push(chunk); next(); }
}

createServer(async (request, response) => {
    // ignore favicon calls
    if (request.url.indexOf("favicon.ico") > -1) { return response.end(); }
    // trigger resize call and pass buffer of original image file
    const { normalisedImage, originalImage } = await resizeJpeg(readFileSync(`${__dirname}/30mb.jpg`));
    // respond stringified json
    response.end(
        JSON.stringify({
            normalisedImage: { size: normalisedImage.size, width: normalisedImage.width, height: normalisedImage.height, quality: normalisedImage.quality },
            originalImage: { size: originalImage.size, width: originalImage.width, height: originalImage.height, quality: originalImage.quality }
        }, null, 4));
}).listen(3000, () => console.log("server started"));
```

As you can see, `resizeJpeg function` has both the approaches implemented.

To make this work you just need to make sure `30mb.jpg` file exists in same directory.

The image I used is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1muJ8UfgP_wsV49DT4p9siXTUc3dmI-5u/view?usp=sharing)

In case you're using linux, following `top command` can be used to monitor the memory usage assuming file name is `so.js` -

top `ps -ef | grep 'so.js' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/.*/-p &/' | xargs echo -c`

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: I did not get a proper solution to this issue to be honest. But what I have noticed is - the amount of memory (RSS) consumed by a Node process depends on the total amount of memory available on the server. If there is enough memory available, Node process postpones execution of garbage collection cycle whenever possible to minimise the downtime. Check this question I asked where you can see that even if RSS memory usage is high, total heap used is under limits - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078647/issue-with-nodejs-memory-consumption-statistics-huge-rss-external-memory-usa

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an issue related to their **memory allocator**.

In their official docs https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#linux-memory-allocator they **recommend** switching to use **jemalloc** to solve this issue.

In short, to solve it you must:

```
apt-get install libjemalloc2

export ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2
```

You may also need this (I'm not sure):

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Sources:

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1041

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/955#issuecomment-475532037